# Unix Program (not ab) to create local requests to local server with different IP addresses

Tags: networking, apache-httpd, ip, testing

I made a module for apache and want to test it across thousands of different IP addresses in a short time.

Currently, my only option is to integrate the module onto a live server for which I have root access, but I don't want the live server to be my test environment.

The only program I have for unix which does mostly what I want is apache bench (ab), but the problem with it is that the source IP address is always constant. I want the source address to always be different.

Can anyone advise me of a program for unix that does what I want?

I don't need a GUI based program.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you hoping to gain by changing the source IP? Does the module's internal logic record or use source IP's at some point?

Comment: But to answer your question [jmeter can change the source IP address](http://jmeter.apache.org/images/screenshots/http-request.png) and you can kick it off from the command line if that's your preferred method.

Comment: Do you need the replies from the server? If not, you could send raw packets with faked ip-adresses.

Comment: looks like `curl` also lets you specify the interface with `--interface` so you might set up a bunch of subinterfaces using some kind of loop and then loop through each of the interfaces you created that way.

Comment: @Bratchley when a server is asked to display a web page, functions in the modules in apache (including mine) are executed with parameters passed into the functions which include the IP address it picks up. I want to test my module with apache picking up different IP addresses without a real connection to the internet to make sure everything works regardless of IP address. and yes my module records IP address in system memory and creates a record about each one (more like a tracking record)

Answer (score 0):

This unix script I made just now does what I want for 256 IP addresses which for now is good enough for me.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo " ";
a=2;
while [ $a -lt 255 ]
do
    echo "Trying source 127.0.0.$a";
    ifconfig lo 127.0.0.$a
    curl -s --interface lo 127.0.0.1:81/ap3/ > /dev/null
    if [ "$?" -ne "0" ];
    then
        echo "curl has a problem with source IP 127.0.0.$a";
        a=256;
    fi
    a=`expr $a + 1`
done
ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1
echo " ";
```